# Why date range return empty query?

Tags: django, model, python-3.6

I try to create a range for my render but i only have empty query when i use `now()` or `date.today()` for filter episode by date.

models.py:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
   date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=now)
```

I import the good library for the process :

```
from django.utils.timezone import now, timedelta
```

I think it's the good way :

```
page = 0
n = now()
Episode.objects.filter(date__range=[n-timedelta(days=(5*page)), n-timedelta(days=(5*(page+1)))])
<QuerySet []>
```

But it's did not work...
For info : database have episodes and values who are typed datetime.datetime :

```
for e in Episode.objects.filter():
   print(e.date)

2017-02-22 19:12:31.351811+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.418354+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.468889+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.524925+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.599978+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.680029+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.744071+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.803611+00:00
2017-02-22 19:12:31.872156+00:00
2017-02-22 22:24:56.733546+00:00
2017-02-23 19:16:00.600644+00:00
```

And when i use string direclty in the range it's work...

```
Episode.objects.filter(date__range=['2017-02-22 19:12:31.351811+00:00','2017-02-22 19:12:31.744071+00:00'])
<QuerySet [<Episode: Episode object>, <Episode: Episode object>, <Episode: Episode object>, <Episode: Episode object>, <Episode: Episode object>, <Episode: Episode object>, <Episode: Episode object>]>
```

I try to initialise variables before too...

```
n = now()
page = 0
startDate = n-timedelta(days=5*page)
endDate = n-timedelta(days=5*(page+1))
Episode.objects.filter(date__range=[startDate, endDate])
<QuerySet []>
```

Do you have an idear why i can filter with `now` or `datetime` and it's work with a string ?

EDIT: The query

```
print(Episode.objects.filter(date__range=[startDate, endDate]).query)
SELECT "table_episode"."id", "table_episode"."card_id", "table_episode"."date", "table_episode"."number", "table_episode"."title", "table_episode"."type_episode", "table_episode"."tag", "table_episode"."url_access" FROM "table_episode" WHERE "table_episode"."date" BETWEEN 2017-02-23 22:46:06.391779 AND 2017-02-18 22:46:06.391779
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: You could print the queryset query and check the generated sql for hints:
`print Episode.objects.filter(date__range=[n-timedelta(days=(5*page)), n-timedelta(days=(5*(page+1)))]).query`

Comment: Thank to your reply, i don't think to do that, i add it to the main post.

Comment: `endDate = n-timedelta(days=5*(page+1))`  endDate will be always lesser than startDate. Check that conditions. Hope it helps

Comment: Ho thank you so mutch ! All pepole talk about `startDate` and `endDate` in the range but no one talk about startDate (present date) will be in second position. I post the result code if someone need it a day.

Comment: @Buky you need to understand that __range is calling sql BETWEEN function for which first argument is greater or equal and second one is less or equal.

Comment: Ok. I understand now... why it's don't write it like that in the documentation. Your explication is very clear, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @alfredo138923 for is help.

I post the solution with explication for anyone who need it a day maybe.

```
page = 0
n = now()
startDate = n-timedelta(days=5*page)     #more recently date
endDate = n-timedelta(days=5*(page+1))   #more older date
Episode.objects.filter(date__range=[endDate, startDate])   #range of 5 days
```

I fact when you need to filter date you use `__range` but the more recently date need to be in the seconde position and oldly date in the first.

```
page = 0
n = now()
Episode.objects.filter(date__range=[n-timedelta(days=(5*(page+1))), n-timedelta(days=(5*page))])
```

Same code but in one line/query.

Citation of the commentary for anyone who doesn't read it :

> `__range` is calling sql BETWEEN function for which first argument is greater or equal and second one is less or equal. – @iklinac

Answer (score 0):

If your page = 0

```
startDate = n  (as page = 0)
endDate = n - 5 days
```

which translates into query that searches between start date now and end date 5 days before getting 0 results

[range documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range)